# Would a question regarding upgrade options be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic

I have an older DX Nikon body, and am unsure about my options for upgrading while still using my existing DX lenses.  Would such a question be on topic for this site - ie it'd boil down to essentially "am I stuck with the latest DX-bodies, despite them being 4 or 5 years old, or are the lenses I have usable on the newer mirrorless Z-series, if so, to what degree of usefulness".

I'm not looking for product recommendations or anything of that nature, just general compatibility between my existing kit and potential future proofing of a fairly substantial purchase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a [canonical question on lens compatibility](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y); most questions along the lines you're asking will tend to get redirected to that one as we don't feel it's valuable to have a separate question for every possible combination of X and Y.

Comment: I don't think that answer is correct. The FTZ adapter will allow most F mount lenses, including most (all?) DX lenses to be mounted on a Z body. Z7 Will auto crop to DX. Z6 is already crop.

Comment: Thanks for that link - hadn't found that Q&A! @scottbb Thanks for that small bit of info too, also useful.

Comment: Yeah, I'm completely backwards on compatibility. You _can_ use DX lenses on a Z camera, me stupid.

Comment: Yeah, my current thinking as of now is that I shouldn't worry about the DX->Z aspect, it's still more of a DX->full frame/cropping issue (though even with cropping, the higher density sensors of the newer cameras will still have more resolution than my old one!), with the F->Z being a complete non-issue with the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to have answered this in comments to Philip's answer, but actually, I think this would be a good Nikon canonical question on Main. I think it's on-topic.

Comment: We already have several that are near canonical in terms of the content of their answers.

Comment: @MichaelC We don't have a "Can I use my Nikon DX lenses on a Z-series body?" question. It's a straightforward and answerable question that would pop up in a google search pretty easily

Answer (score 0):

We already have quite a few similar questions about using Nikon DX lenses on Nikon FX cameras. Surely one or more of them already answer your own question?

[DX vs FX the final comparison](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/26363/15871)
[What compromises are there shooting DX lenses on an FX camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/47089/15871)
[Do any Nikon FX cameras allow square-format shooting with DX lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/21025/15871)
[Is there a benefit to using a FX body when using DX Lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/52854/15871)
[Will using a DX lens on an FX Body compromise ISO performance?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/61259/15871)
[Other than the vignetting, what am I missing by using my Nikkor 35mm f/1.8 DX on an FX camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/70731/15871)
[Does a Nikon DX lens on a FX camera get subjected to the 1.5X crop factor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/7824/15871)
[Crop Factor: Can a full-frame Nikon Camera be set to use a DX lens, with no crop-factor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/70376/15871)
[Can Nikon FX (full-frame) users use DX (APS-C) lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/27301/15871)
[Are cropped images from a full-frame sensor equal quality to full APS-C images despite the lower resolution?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/27466/15871)

Free bonus for no additional charge:

[How to transition from crop-frame to full-frame](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/77032/15871)

Comment: As I understood it, the question in question (?) would be about using DX on Z bodies. None of what you linked to mentions Z (the questions predate Z system).

Comment: @scottbb "Yeah, my current thinking as of now is that I shouldn't worry about the DX->Z aspect, it's still more of a DX->full frame/cropping issue (though even with cropping, the higher density sensors of the newer cameras will still have more resolution than my old one!), with the F->Z being a complete non-issue with the adapter. – 
James Thorpe- yesterday"

Comment: But that wasn't in the question. That was evolved understanding in the comments, in a Meta question. It doesn't change my opinion that a question about mounting DX lenses on Z bodies is a good question to have on Main.